# How to get part of a string in Java and print it?

Tags: java

For example I would get an input from the user for an unspecified amount of characters and add them to a string, I then use the `if input1.toLowerCase().startsWith(input2.toLowerCase()))` to detect if the first part of both strings are the same. In this case, `input1` and `input2` are both strings picked up with a scanner.

How do I print the same parts of each string?

For example if I enter "Hi my name is" for `input1` and "Hi my name" for `input2`, it should output "Hi my name"

EDIT: To clarify, I convert the strings to lowercase and then attempt to compare the two with `startsWith` casing doesn't matter in this problem

Comment: You'll just print input2 out because that's what's gonna be common between the two because your condition uses startsWith().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the largest starting string from two strings, you need to test each character separately:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < str1.length() && i < str2.length() && str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(i); i++);
String common = str1.substring(0, i);
```

Comment: Okay this actually works for the most part _except_ when the first string is longer than the second string (It knocks off one letter). I can actually offset it to fix it, but why is it doing that?

Comment: @Nero-One (with the typo corrected - see latest edit) works for me: If I set  `String str1 = "abcde"; String str2 = "abc";` result is `"abc"`

Answer (score 0):

Your logic should flow in this way:

- First check if input1 and input2 are the same
- Then check if input1 startsWith input2

  - If true, then print input2
  - Else, check if its the other way around (input2 startsWith input1)

    - If true, then you should print input1

Try to create this code yourself - its the best way to learn coding: trial and error! Remember this is software programming - nothing is going to blow up when you encounter a Java compiler error.